How to Configure SE_SESSION_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, SE_NEW_SESSION_THREAD_POOL_SIZE, and SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT for Selenium Grid in Kubernetes?
I'm currently running a Selenium Grid setup on a Kubernetes cluster, with edge nodes configured to scale between a minimum of 5 replicas and a maximum of 100 replicas. My use case involves executing 1000+ concurrent sessions, where each session takes at least 10 minutes to complete. This means that each node will run approximately 10 sessions simultaneously, and the total time to complete all sessions will be around 100 minutes. Consequently, the last session will need to remain in the queue for up to 90 minutes.
Given this scenario, I have a few questions about the following Selenium Grid environment variables:

SE_SESSION_REQUEST_TIMEOUT: How does this variable impact my setup,
especially considering that some sessions will be in the queue for
up to 90 minutes?

SE_NEW_SESSION_THREAD_POOL_SIZE: Given that I have 100 nodes and
1000+ concurrent sessions, do I need to configure this variable on
the hub? If so, what would be an appropriate value?

SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT: What is the practical use of this variable
in my scenario, and how should it be set to ensure optimal
performance and reliability of the sessions?


I know the basic definitions of these variables but I need more insights on how to use these exactly in my setup. Any detailed explanations or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.
